# An algorithm to solve a problem at minimal complexity

Tags: algorithms

I have the following problem: Suppose there is an infinite list which is fully populated up to a certain point $k$ after which it's empty. I need to suggest an algorithm to find $k$ while checking as few entries in the list (asymptotically) and prove that it is indeed of minimal complexity.

One idea I had was to check the $2^i$ entries for $i\in\mathbb{N}$ till I find an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $2^n$ is populated and $2^{\left(n+1\right)}$ isn't. Then run a binary search on all the entries between those two values. It would find $k$ but I have no idea whether it's of minimal complexity or how to even begin to analyze that question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I suspect that you have a function $\mathtt{isempty} : \mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$. If there is nothing about cost, then probably it is $O(1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do any better than $O(\log_2 k)$. In any range, $[2^n,2^{n+1})$, there are $2^n$ different values for $k$. We therefore require at least one of those values to take $n$ tests (because there are only $2^{n-1}$ possible sequences of test results with fewer tests.)

So for some $k\in [2^n,2^{n+1})$ the number of steps is at least $n=\left\lfloor\log_2 k\right\rfloor$.

Comment: Even if the binary search is the optimal solution for the range $\left[2^{n},2^{n+1}\right)$ how do I also work into the complexity the part where I check every $2^i$ entry and show that it's still optimal together?

Comment: It takes $1+\log_2 k$ trials to find $n$ so that $k\in[2^n,2^{n+1})$ and then $\log_2 k$ trials to do the binary search. This all assumes the integer arithmetic is $O(1)$, which is, I suppose, unrealistic, but it gives your algorithm a complexity of $O(\log k)$

Answer (score 0):

Surely, you can find $k$ in $O(\log k)$ time (for example, using the algorithm you described). The question is can you do it faster? The answer is no, you can't. The reason is that whatever the $k$ is, you need to *construct it* using arithmetical operations (addition, multiplication, bit shift, etc.). However, you cannot construct such a number in less than $\Theta(\log k)$ steps, and this is the lower bound for your algorithm (take note, that for very large numbers multiplication takes much more than $O(1)$ time!).

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could elaborate more specifically how you achieve the lower bound.

Comment: Use your algorithm and show that for any $k$ it does $O(\log k)$ steps.

Comment: Ye but how do I show there is no other algorithm with better complexity? 
I'm quite new to the whole field of algorithms and complexity so I didn't really get what you meant about not being able to construct $k$ more efficiently than    $\Omega\left(\log k\right)$

Comment: If you were to construct $k$ in memory, then you would need write somewhere every digit and every such action takes some (constant) time. $k$ has $\log k$ digits, you need to use at least that much time. This works even if you can specify $k$ with some other rules, as there exist numbers with [Kolmogorov complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) equal their length times constant.

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase the problem: The adversary selects some natural number and provides you with an oracle which will tell you whether a number of your choice is greater or less than the secret number. You want to find the secret in the fewest possible tries.

The first question to consider is what a reasonable complexity measure would be. *Average* complexity is out because it would depend on the probability distribution with which the adversary selects various number, and there's no "natural" probability distribution on $\mathbb N$ we can assume in default of better information.

The only thing that seems to make good sense is considering how the running time of an algorithm grows as a function of the adversary's unknown number. We could consider ordinary asymptotic growth here (that is, ignoring constant factors), but since "number of questions to the oracle" is a well-defined unit of complexity, we can be slightly more precise and only ignore constant *terms*.

The counting argument Thomas Andrews presents shows that any correct algorithm must use at least $\log_2 k \pm c$ questions in the limit to locate the number $k$, for some constant $c$.

The doubling-then-binary-search algorithm you suggest will use $2\log_2 k \pm c$ questions in the limit -- namely first $\log_2 k$ questions to determine the size of $k$ and then $\log_2 k$ questions the discover its lower-order bits. The constant $c$ depends on how large your *initial* guess is; you can get as large a negative $c$ simply my making your *initial* guess in the doubling phase large. (This is why we might as well ignore constant terms in the number of questions; they can be traded for more time spent in a bounded initial range of $k$s).

What's the best $a$ such that there's an algorithm that uses at most $a\log_2 k + c$ questions in the limit? So far we have the bounds $1\le a\le 2$; can we narrow down that interval? I don't know.